# Why do I get a AuthenticationException when invoking the EJB remotely on TomEE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have a ejb running on a TomEE 7.0.3 server. btw, all this was working in Tomee 1.7.4.
I have setup a set of users using the tomcat-users.xml file

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin" />
    <role rolename="admin-gui" />
    <role rolename="admin-script" />
    <role rolename="manager" />
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />
    <role rolename="manager-script" />
    <role rolename="manager-jmx" />
    <role rolename="manager-status" />
    <role rolename="tomee-admin" />
    <user
        name="admin"
        password="admin"
        roles="admin,manager,admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,tomee-admin" />
    <role rolename="tomcat" />
    <user
        name="tomcat"
        password="tomcat"
        roles="tomcat" />
    <user
        name="manager"
        password="manager"
        roles="manager" />
</tomcat-users>
```

I am able able to access the url http://127.0.0.1/tomee/ejb by providing the credentials for user 'admin'.
My server.xml file has the following entries

```
<Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved"
    factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase"
    pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />
```

and

```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI resources 
            under the key "UserDatabase". Any edits that are performed against this UserDatabase 
            are immediately available for use by the Realm. -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
            resourceName="UserDatabase" />
    </Realm>
```

The problem is when I try to invoke the ejb remotely, my JNDI InitialContext uses the following properties.

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http://127.0.0.1:8082/tomee/ejb
java.naming.security.principal=admin
java.naming.security.credentials=admin
```

Following is the code for calling the ejb.

```
public static Object locateService(String serviceName) throws NamingException, IOException {
    InputStream in = ServiceLocator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("servicelocator.properties");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(in);
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);
    return ctx.lookup("PaymentManagerRemote");
}
```

As you can see I am supplying the correct username and password but I get the following exception

```
Apr 27, 2017 12:39:07 PM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
INFO: RemoteInitialContextCreated{providerUri=http://127.0.0.1:8082/tomee/ejb}
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Error while communicating with server: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.naming.AuthenticationException
    at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.authenticate(JNDIContext.java:381)
    at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.getInitialContext(JNDIContext.java:289)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at co.uk.meghdoot.core.util.ServiceLocator.locateService(ServiceLocator.java:20)
    at co.uk.meghdoot.core.test.DeviceLocationTest.setUp(DeviceLocationTest.java:53)
    at co.uk.meghdoot.core.test.DeviceLocationTest.main(DeviceLocationTest.java:109)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

using tomcat-users.xml assumes you used UserDatabaseRealm as realm in server.xml which is maybe not the case (not written in your question). This also assume the authentication is done through servlet/tomcat backbone. This is not the case by default until you added in tomee webapp (you can create it physically and define the ejbd servlet - see http://tomee.apache.org/ejbd-transport.html - a filter doing a request.login().

Using ejbd protocol tomee will automatically log in using tomee security service which will rely on the first realm of the server.xml by default.

Comment: I have gone through the link that you sent the error I get is a AuthenticationException not a Serialization error. More over with makeing any changes to the whitelist and blacklist, I should be able to call the remote ejb, the default blacklist should work without any changes.

Comment: did you also setup jaas properly (JVM system property + JAASRealm)?

Comment: No, I have not setup JAAS realm. Is it a requirement for the new version of tomee? Can you point to some documentation.

Comment: Not for the new tomee, it always relied on JAAS when bypassing tomcat layers (ejbd). this post explains how to set it up https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/create-a-tomee-accessible-through-ssh-with-tomee-maven-plugin/

Comment: I am able to see the page localhost:8080/tomee/ejb from the browser so why can't the remote client see it?

Comment: did you create this webapp yourself? this shouldnt be in the default distribution anymore cause it is no more needed.

Comment: I downloaded the tomee-webaccess-7.0.3.war file and renamed it to tomee.war and copied it to the webapps folder. But the point again is that I want to access my ejbs using the users and roles in tomcat-users.xml. I don't mind a different url.

Comment: I see, webaccess is not the ejbd webapp, you don't need it at all and it can kind of disable/change the config of ejbd if you name it tomee. You can reuse tomcat-users.xml as shown by the sample at https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/examples/simple-remote-tomcatusers

Comment: I get the following error when I tried to build the project in your link.

Result: Tests in error: 
  XAPoolTest.check » Construction Error invoking factory method: public static o...

Tests run: 3875, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 2

Comment: hmm, don't think you built the project i linked but you built the whole tomee project. Just go in examples/simple-remote-tomcatusers folder, maybe update tomee version to 7.0.3 (or keep the snapshot) and build it. You don'tt need to build tomee itself

Comment: I have built just the example but I notice the test uses http://localhost:%s/tomee/ejb url and not ejbd.